# Tags are not properly displayed in new tabs UI

Tags: bug, status-norepro, tags, new-nav

Below is how tags show up in the new tabs when I click on `jquery-ui*` in favorites:

> [image]

It's not utilizing the full width and looks ugly.

Ideally it should start from the first tag and utilize the maximum space available.

Comment: This is no longer relevant after the tabs were reorganized